# Can Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard read USB NTFS drives?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, ntfs

I need to take a 25 GB VM home from my work PC to my home [iMac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac). I have a USB drive here formatted as NTFS. Will my iMac be able to read it (Snow Leopard) at home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All versions of Mac OS X, at least past 10.2, can read NTFS.  USB, Firewire, network drive, doesn't matter...

According to Wikipedia, it supports HFS+ (default), HFS, UFS, AFP, ISO 9660, FAT, UDF, NFS, SMBFS, NTFS (read only), FTP, WebDAV, ZFS (experimental).  Snow Leopard, assuming you re-install the boot camp drivers, allows your Windows OS to read HFS+ via the said boot camp drivers....

So even two way access is allowed...

Comment: I'll try this at home tonight. I don't use Bootcamp, I use VMWare Fusion, so do I have to install Bootcamp for read/write access?

Comment: The boot camp drivers can be used a virtual machine, so that should work...  I actually disable it on my system, since I don't want a Windows virus to possibly wipe out my Mac disks...

Answer (score 0):

You can boot your Mac with a Linux LiveCD. From there you can easily mount the HFS+ partition and the NTFS partition, and move files from the HFS+ to the NTFS or directly write in the NTFS. Writing in the HFS+ needs installing drivers and it is not very safe to use.